# Can the below function be called as pure function(JS)?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, purely-functional

I was recently going through javascript pure functions. I found out that the pure function should not have any global dependencies, so according to this i encountered a doubt which i have try to explain below.

```
function parent(){

 const count =1;
 const data = 30;

 function child (){
    let sum = count + data;
    return sum;
 }

 function child2(count, data){

    let final = count + data;
    return final;
 }
}
```

So according to the above snippet, can the child and child2 function be called as pure function? If child function is called as pure function they why because it is taking the parameters from the parent function defined above.

The output of both the functions will be same but which one would be called as pure function. This might be a very simple question but any help will be useful.

Comment: What's your definition of "purely functional"? Neither have "side effect" or modify data so I'd say both are, but this is open to conjecture

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function Is the return value the same for the same argumenta? Yes for both, because `count` and `data` are static/constant, and so `child` will always return the same value. Do the functions have side effects? No. So both functions are pure.

Answer (score 0):

It's only about scope and variables

```js
function parent(){
  //
  // Parent function scope
  let count = 1;
  let data = 30;

  function child(){
    //
    // Child scope
    let sum = count + data;
    //
    // Change variable 'count' in PARENT scope
    count = 10;
    //
    // Return
    return sum;
  }

  //
  // Result will be 31
  const res1 = child();
  console.log(`Result 1: ${res1}`);

  function child2(count, data){
    //
    // Child2 scope
    let final = count + data;
    //
    // Change variable 'count' in child2 (CURRENT) scope
    count = 20;
    //
    // Return
    return final;
  }

  //
  // Result will be 40
  const res2 = child2(count, data);
  console.log(`Result 2: ${res2}`);

  //
  // Result will be 40
  const res3 = child();
  console.log(`Result 3: ${res3}`);
}

// Run parent
parent();
```

Comment: Yes, i got it that its all about scope and variables, but what about pure function over here ?

Answer (score 0):

A pure function is a function that do not have any dependency and will return a same result with same arguments **everywhere**. you can move *child2* function to another file and that will work as well but you can not more *child* function anywhere because it needs the variables outside of it's scope. so the answer is: the *child* function is not pure and the *child2* function is pure.

Comment: I don't think being relocatable is a requirement for being pure. Do you have a source? But either, after thinking a bit more about it, I don't think `child2` is pure. Consider the following example that passes the same argument but yields different results: `function child2(count, data){ return count + data;}; var v = {valueOf() { return 42; }};  console.log(child2(v, 1)); v.valueOf = () => 21; console.log(child2(v, 1));`

Comment: @FelixKling I said that must be relocatable to convey that it must not be affected by another scopes. and about your example, actually v object is changed, so we do not pass the same argument as before. so I don't think we can say child2 is not pure for this explanation. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-functions/

Comment: `v` was mutated but it's still the same object. Granted that may be a grey area. But it's similar to the example for impure functions in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function#Impure_functions) (*"... return value variation with a mutable reference argument"*)

Comment: @FelixKling yeah you're right. so do you think if we add type checking, will it be a pure function?